# The file corrupted error in building Windows Universal Store App

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I am getting following error for all xaml files after building `Windows Universal Store App`

```
The file or directory is corrupted or unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070570)
```

Should i reinstall some SDKs?

Comment: What is shown in your Pending Changes?

Comment: Nothing, since i l deleted everything and downloaded again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and also I wasn't able to create new project. Re-Installing the SDKs wouldn't solve the problem instead try to reset your visual studio settings

Tools>Import and Export Settings>Reset all Settings

It worked for me.